# Um efeito de 'tremida' com while?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1

Estou usando o seguinte código dentro de um Timer:

```
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x, y;
            int cont = 0;
            x = tt.X;
            y = tt.Y;
            while(cont < 5)
            {
                tt.X += cont;
                tt.Y += cont;
                cont++;
            }
            while(cont > 0)
            {
                tt.X -= cont;
                tt.Y -= cont;
                cont--;
            }
            tt.X = x;
            tt.Y = y;
        }
```

Seria para um botão, alterar a posição de seu X e Y para dar um efeito como se ele estivesse tremendo, como faço isso? Com esse código ele fica parado, tirando as duas últimas linhas, ele fica apenas subindo na tela.

Tentei assim para fazer um efeito meio brusco:

```
 double x, y;
            int cont = 0;
            x = tt.X; //armazana varaivel X para manipulação
            y = tt.Y; //backup da variavel Y

            while (cont < 20)
            {
                if(dt.Interval.TotalSeconds % 2 == 0)
                {
                    tt.X = (20 - cont);
                }
                else
                {
                    tt.X = (20 - cont);
                }

                cont++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou te passar uma ideia de como você faria isso.

Vou fazer em windows forms mesmo só para você ter uma ideia.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;
            int by;
            int cont = 0;
            x = button1.Location.X; //armazana varaivel X para manipulação
            by = button1.Location.Y; //backup da variavel Y

            //vamos fazer o botão tremer 20 vezes decrementando ele para posição inicial
            //isso vai dar o efeito de tremida mais suave
            while (cont < 20)
            {
                //desloca 20 para a direita, depois vai deslocar 19 e por ai vai até a posição ser a inicial do botão
                button1.Location = new Point(x += (20 - cont), by);
                //aguarda 20 milisegundos para dar tempo de nosso cerebro interpretar e reconhecer o deslocamento
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);

                //desloca para o centro novamente
                button1.Location = new Point(x -= (20 - cont), by);
                //aguarda 20 milisegundos para dar tempo de nosso cerebro interpretar e reconhecer o deslocamento
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);

                //desloca 20 para a esquerda, depois vai deslocar 19 e por ai vai até a posição ser a inicial do botão
                button1.Location = new Point(x -= (20 - cont), by);
                //aguarda 20 milisegundos para dar tempo de nosso cerebro interpretar e reconhecer o deslocamento
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);

                //desloca para o centro novamente
                button1.Location = new Point(x += (20 - cont), by);
                //aguarda 20 milisegundos para dar tempo de nosso cerebro interpretar e reconhecer o deslocamento
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);

                cont++;
            }
        }
```

O ideal é não usar o System.Threading.Thread.Sleep e sim armazenar sua lógica dentro de um timer.

Mais o importante é que entre um deslocamento e outro você deve dar um pause para que o nosso cerebro consiga interpretar a informação visual, caso contrário é tão rápido que para nós parece que não saiu do lugar.

E também manipular os deslocamentos para que faça o efeito de tremer e não simplesmente desloque N pixels para o eixo X e depois contrário e boa. Isso não funciona.

Pode criar um projeto windows form ai e testar o código ou adaptar direto para o seu projeto.

Comment: Não deu muito certo, com Sleep deu aspecto lento á aplicação, e o efeito não funcionou, daí fiz umas alterações, a primeira ele ficou doidão, indo para esquerda, a outra ele só deu um passinho e parou.. Atualizei no post

Comment: Então como eu disse não fiz em windows phone o projeto então o sleep é muito custoso para o mobile. mas a ideia é a seguinte. Mexa o botão 20 pixels para a direita (pausa de +/- 20 milisegundos) volte o botão ao centro (20 pixels para esqueda) mexa o botão 20 pixels para a esquerda (pausa de +/- 20 milisegundos) e volte o botão ao centro (20 pixels para direita). Depois disso decrementa 1 e faz tudo novamente.

Comment: Se você não conseguir resolver até a noite eu posto uma resposta a noite para o windows phone.

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho dê uma lida nisto, não te ajuda diretamente mas eu fiz porque eu vejo que todo mundo usa o recurso de forma errada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101