# Como fazer a aplicação esperar por um tempo?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, timer

É comum termos situações que precisamos atrasar a execução do código por um período, seja para mostrar ou apagar uma mensagem ou algo visual pouco depois, seja para tentar algo novamente, esperar por algo em um teste ou algo criativo que resolva um problema ou cause um novo.

O comum é usar:

```
Thread.Sleep(3000)
```

Isto está correto?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

De fato esta é a forma usual e está correta se quer travar a *thread* atual (que muitas vezes é a principal e portanto trava toda a aplicação).

Mas em geral não é o que se deseja de fato. Normalmente só é útil em testes e depuração. Travar é diferente de bloquear embora o efeito final parece igual em muitos casos.

E mesmo que seja o desejado, ela tem problemas. Isto cria uma *thread* que é algo pesado. Consome **bastante** memória e gasta muito processamento para sua criação e gerenciamento (troca de contexto).

Você deve estar pensando "e daí que gasta processamento?". Tira capacidade que poderia estar sendo usada por outras aplicações em um computador. Em dispositivo móvel também está consumindo bateria. Você realmente quer isto ou usa sem pensar nas consequências?

Como na maior parte do tempo você quer apenas atrasar a execução de um código e o travamento da aplicação é um efeito desnecessário ou mesmo indesejável, tem que fazer isto de outra forma.

Antes do .NET 4.5 teria que construir um código mais complexo para controlar isto, talvez usando [`WaitHandles`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Mas nesta versão é possível usar a assincronicidade para ajudar.

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/Delay2.cs).

Com o método [`Task.Delay()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_) se obtêm o atraso desejado de forma muito mais leve e com o [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101) isto é feito sem travar a aplicação.

É possível inclusive criar um *token* de cancelamento e parar o atraso, algo que pode ser desejável em alguns casos.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gk4Pps). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8edZHa). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/Delay.cs).

Nessa [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15341962/221800) tem algumas soluções para quem usa versão anterior do .NET. [Artigo mostrando como o `TaskDelay()` funciona e como reproduzi-lo](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/async-taskdelay.html).

Uma informação adicional é que estes atrasos ocorrem através de um *timer* e a precisão dele é baixa. Depende do sistema operacional. No Windows atual, pelo menos para desktop, gira em torno de 15ms. Então não só não adianta usar números menores que este mas também você não pode ter nada fora de múltiplos disto.

Comment: Adicionaria ainda o facto de, com o uso de `Task.Delay`, *nenhuma* thread ficar ocupada esperando o timeout. Portanto, não é equivalente a `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(3000))`, ao contrário do que se possa pensar. Com `Task.Delay`, as threads ficam todas livres, e o sistema operativo irá notificar a nossa aplicação através duma IOCP (I/O Completion Port) 3 segundos depois.

Comment: Concordo com a ideia geral, de uma certa forma foi o que eu coloquei na resposta. Posso estar enganado, ou posso não ter entendido o que você quis dizer, mas nos dois casos há uma notificação do SO quando deve terminar o intervalo. A diferença é apenas no bloqueio. O `Sleep()` não fica executando nada.

Comment: A diferença entre `Sleep` e `Delay`, sim, é "apenas" no bloqueio (falando de um modo simples). Eu estava apenas a esclarecer a diferenca entre `await Task.Delay(x)` e `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(x))`, que algumas pessoas pensam ser equivalentes. No primeiro, todas as threads ficam livres - no segundo, uma thread da ThreadPool fica ocupada.