# Como eu posso gerar um atraso durante a execução de uma aplicação no Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou criando uma aplicação no Unity e preciso de alguma função que ocasione um delay durante a execução da aplicação.

Comment: Eu acho que é isto que deseja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101

Answer (score 1):

Para execução assíncrona, bem como delay, existe Co-Routines na Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        print("Iniciando " + Time.time);
        StartCoroutine(EsperarImprimir(2.0F));
        print("Antes da Co-Routine acabar " Time.time);
    }
    IEnumerator EsperarImprimir(float waitTime) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("EsperarImprimir " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

Se você quiser continuar executando o código de baixo somente depois da Co-Routine acabar (somente depois do delay), use yield return:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    IEnumerator Start() {
        print("Início " + Time.time);
        yield return StartCoroutine(EsperaImprime(2.0F));
        print("Fim, depois da coroutine executar " + Time.time);
    }
    IEnumerator EsperaImprime(float waitTime) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("EsperaImprime " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

Você também pode chamar coroutines passando nome das funções via String. Enfim, confira a documentação em http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html