# Relação entre o método "InitializeComponent();" e o carregamento de uma "Splash Screen"

Tags: c#, wpf

Adicionei uma *splash screen* a um projeto da forma mais simples, ou seja, alterando a propriedade *Build Action* para *SplashScreen*.
Embora com efeitos visuais muito semelhantes, o que se passa realmente quando comparamos estas duas soluções?

**A**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

**B**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, é importante você saber o que se passa no método `InitializeComponent()`. Ele é responsável por criar, adicionar e posicionar todos os componentes na tela.

Então, qual a diferença entre a sulução **A** e a solução **B**?

Na solução **A**, os componentes são criados e é dado um `Sleep()` de 5 segundos **depois de todos os componentes terem sidos criados**.

Na solução **B**, primeiro é dado um `Sleep()` de 5 segundos e só depois que esse tempo passa é que os componentes vão ser criados.

---

É interessante mencionar que `Thread.Sleep()` trava a interface gráfica, se você estiver usando .NET Framework 4.5 ou posterior pode testar `await Task.Sleep(5000);`.

Mais informações [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/18246)

Comment: Então eu só não noto a diferença porque, como a mainwindow está vazia, é tão rápido que não se nota a diferença entre o antes e o depois?

Comment: Não vai notar a diferença, pois esse Sleep é executado no construtor. Veja no seu Program.cs, ele cria um form (é nesse ponto que vai ocorrer o Sleep), e passa o form para o aplication.Run. O application que vai mostrar o form em sí....