# Diferença entre Task e Thread

Tags: c#, .net, thread, multithreading, task

Preciso criar um executável c# e ficou a duvida: Fazer com `thread` ou fazer com `task`?

- Na prática existe alguma diferença entre usar `Task` e o "tradicional" `multi-thread`??
- É verdade que uma `task` pode ter várias `threads`?

Basicamente meu executável terá 5 chamadas diferentes, que podem ser executadas ao mesmo tempo.

Como tratam-se de chamadas individuais, eu quero evitar que uma execute somente quando a outra termine e simplesmente executar todas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- [`Thread`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) é algo mais próximo do concreto. Toda implementação no .NET segue basicamente o que o sistema operacional oferece. Você usa quando precisa lidar especificamente com *thread*. Note que é comum algumas pessoas pensarem em *thread* quando ela só quer paralelismo ou mesmo assincronicidade. *Thread* é uma forma de atingir isso, mas não a única. Podemos chamar de mecanismo.
- [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0) é algo mais abstrato. É algo que foi criado no .NET para o programador não ter que lidar com os detalhes do paralelismo ou assincronicidade. Quando se usa uma tarefa está dizendo que precisa de algo pronto em algum momento futuro. Como isso será realizado é algo que o *framework* pode decidir como fazer melhor. Em geral ele é capaz de fazer isso. Podemos considerá-lo de regra do negócio (executar assincronamente).

Tem uma chance razoável da tarefa usar uma ou mais *threads* internas para alcançar o objetivo, seja criando *threads* ou usando existentes. De qualquer forma, mesmo quando se fala em criação, muito provavelmente será feito através de um *pool* gerenciado pelo *framework*.

Um exemplo de diferença de como a tarefa escolhe o melhor caminho: o `Thread.Sleep()` consome processamento para esperar um tempo, o [`Task.Delay()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101) cria uma interrupção no processador (através do OS) para o código ser invocado.

## Task é mais poderosa

Há uma série de *ferramentas* na API de `Task` para usar os recursos de forma mais fácil, correta e eficaz. O controle e a comunicação entre as tarefas é muito melhor. Tudo o que precisaria ser feito com *threads* para o bom uso já está pronto e foi realizado por uma equipe que entende do assunto e teve condições de testar adequadamente.

É comum usar tarefas associadas com [`async`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101).

Como será usado em alguma aplicação específica ou qual é melhor é sempre difícil dizer com certeza, principalmente sem muitos detalhes sobre os requisitos. Mas o que se recomenda hoje no .NET é usar *task* por padrão e somente se ela não fornecer tudo o que se espera passar para *thread* ou outra forma mais concreta de obter um resultado futuro que não bloqueie a aplicação.

## Exemplo específico

É um pouco estranho essa definição de 5 camadas que podem ser executadas ao mesmo tempo. Não sei se isto é verdade, ou sequer se precisa dito, mas considerando que seja, a descrição parece exigir apenas assincronicidade, portanto é só pedir para tarefas serem executadas, se precisar criar *threads*, a [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) criará. A TPL tem tudo o que precisa para executar em paralelo.

Recomendo fortemente a leitura dessa [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). Também pode [ler algo sobre a diferença de termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101). Esse [artigo](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) também é bom.

No geral é isso, quando estiver aplicando podem surgir dúvidas específicas que podemos responder.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente, bigown ! Muito obrigado!! Se não for abusar muito da sua boa vontade, tem como explicar como que funciona o assincronismo na Task? E a ideia é *executar* 5 *métodos* diferentes... Em thread eu colocaria as threads em uma `Collection`, iniciaria todas juntas e depois iria percorrer uma a uma para saber qual ainda está ativa...

Comment: Entendi, então não são camadas. Vou se se dá pra complementar na resposta ou se precisa de uma pergunta nova pela complexidade. Pra falar a verdade não conheço muito o funcionamento interno, sei que é complexo. Leu a pergunta sobre `await/async`?

Comment: Eu escrevi "chamada" quando quis dizer *executar* rs... Li sim...em tese o `await` já evita que eu precise percorrer uma lista e fazer a execução individual... posso fazer 5 execuções cada uma com seu `await`?

Comment: Sim, pode, quantas quiser, e se precisar de *thread* para garantir isto, é um problema da `Task` internamente resolver isto, nem o código chamado, nem o chamador precisa saber disto.

Comment: Perfeito! Mais uma vez obrigado :)

Comment: se quiser/puder dar uma olhada nessa pergunta: [Multiplas conexões] (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125172/m%C3%BAltiplas-conex%C3%B5es-com-banco-execut%C3%A1vel-c-com-multi-task) - está diretamente relacionada com essa pergunta :)

Comment: @Maniero Existe em [tag:sistemas-operacionais] (no livro aberto citado na tag tem explicação) o conceito de "tarefa" ou "task", que é mais abstrato (uma sequência de instruções a ser executada uma após a outra), e não é específico do .NET, embora possivelmente `Task` seja uma abstração em cima desse conceito, direta ou com alguma intenção a mais, talvez para isolar a forma de programar do modelo de execução do SO, que hoje já é uma tentativa de promover abstração para a execução de tarefas (com threads de núcleo, de usuário e processos). Talvez a escolha do thread model quebre essa abstração.