# Pra que serve Runnable?

Tags: java, c#, .net, thread

Estava pensando em criar *thread* um no meu software, mas vi pelos fóruns que o `Runnable` ajuda de certa forma na criação de um *thread*, e queria entender como funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desconheço qualquer coisa de `Runnable` em C#, isto é coisa de Java. Esta classe era necessária por uma deficiência no início da linguagem.

Mesmo o uso de *thread* bruta é considerado ultrapassado em C#. Claro que ele pode ser usado, mas o ideal, sempre que possível, que seja adequado, e quase sempre é, [prefira utilizar `Task`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101), que optará por criar/usar *threads* internas, se for necessário.

Se quiser insistir nisso, dê uma olhada em [`ThreadStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Aliás, o que é esse _Runnable_ e por que não temos no C#?

Comment: Provavelmente porque não precisa, tem outros mecanismos melhores.

Comment: `Runnable` é uma interface que obriga a implementar um método sem parâmetros que não retorna nada, esse método por acaso se chama `run()` e contém o código a ser efetivamente executado pela thread, portanto ele é passado para a classe `Thread` disparar a execução do thread no sistema operacional. Por questão de conveniência a classe Thread também implementa a interface Runnable e pode ela mesma conter o código em questão (na verdade uma subclasse dela).