# Task.Run sempre inicia uma nova Thread?

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading, async, task

Ao executa uma lista de tarefas iniciadas através de Task.Run, é garantido que cada uma seja executa em uma Thread diferente?

Ao ler a documentação, me parece que este é o comportamento padrão, ao fazer os testes eu estava validando através do Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.

Sei que as Threads podem ser reaproveitadas, o que eu preciso é que cada uma execute apenas uma Task, de forma isolada, não executando duas Tasks na mesma Thread.

Comment: Nada garante que uma *thread* seja criada, de fato, se uma for necessária provavelmente será usada uma do *thread pool*. Veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101

Comment: @bigown Sim eu entendi, mas por exemplo executando uma serie de tarefas desta forma em um laço, é possível que duas sejam executadas na mesma Thread simultaneamente?

Comment: Até onde eu sei é possível sim, mas não sei se a implementação atual faz isso, menos ainda sei dizer em quais situações ele aproveitaria ou não..

Comment: Entendo que pode haver o reaproveitamento, mas se duas Tasks forem executadas na mesma Thread com o mesmo: 'Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId', tem como forçar seja apenas uma Task por 'Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId' ?

Comment: Não sei dizer, tenho bem pouca experiência com isso, mas espero que alguém consiga te dar uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O .NET usa uma fila (FIFO) para as chamadas de TASK para o método Task.Run, se as chamadas forem muito próximas, ele pode usar uma mesma Thread para duas chamadas de Task.Run para aumentar o desempenho. Mas sempre será uma Thread diferente do método que está o chamando. Olha um exemplo:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id Main: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id Run " + i + ": " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id Thread " + i + ": " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                });
                t.Start();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Nesse exemplo você ver que algumas Task.Run usam a mesma thread. Já a classe Thread sempre usa uma thread diferente. Cada um pode ser muito bem usada em pontos específicos, O Task.Run você pode ganhar desempenho por não ficar precisando instanciar e iniciar uma nova thread para cada ação, mas se cada ação for demorada, como por exemplo a espero de uma conexão via socket, pode ser mais intenressante usar a Thread mesmo, pois senão uma ação fica a espera de outra para ser concluída.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta, está de acordo com os meus testes, as Threads são reutilizadas, mas nunca dois processos rodam simultaneamente na mesma Thread.