# Ajuda com sistema de threards

Tags: c#, thread

Eu escrevi uma pequena aplicação em C#, onde seu principal processo demora muito tempo para ser executado. Estou tendo um problema com a falta de resposta da interface gráfica do aplicativo durante a execução deste processo. Através de ajuda obtida aqui mesmo no *stackoverflow*, fui auxiliado a criar uma *thread* para execução deste processo. No entanto, ainda estou com esse problema de falta de resposta da aplicação durante o processo longo.

Vejam como eu fiz:

```
 private void GeraRelatorio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      Thread geraRelatorio = new Thread(GeraRelatorio_Thread);
      geraRelatorio.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      geraRelatorio.Start();
      return;
 }
```

Eu ainda vou estudar sobre *threads*, mas é que o problema surgiu antes a hora.
Alguém sabe com faço a interface responder durante o processo?

Comment: No [StackOverflow-En](http://stackoverflow.com/a/435691/47733) tem um exemplo bem ilustrativo.

Comment: está usando Windows Form ?

Comment: se estiver em windows forms, utilize o background worker, caso positivo te envio codigo exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma mais fácil de trabalhar com threads é com as `Task`

O seu método ficaria assim:

```
private async void GeraRelatorio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => GeraRelatorio_Thread());           
}
```

Com a `Task` você precisa informar que o seu método é um método assíncrono inserindo na assinatura do método a palavra `async`.

Dentro do seu método você inicializa a `Task` com o método `Task.Run()` passando uma `Action` e dentro da `Action` você chama o seu método que irá rodar em uma thread.

A palavra `await`, a grosso modo, faz com que o controle da execução seja devolvido para a thread que chamou o método `async`.

**Para mais informações:**

[Diferença entre Task e Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/44289)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Como eu configuro Apartment State como STA?

Comment: Não acho que seja necessário, mas se você acha que é, as resposta desta pergunta http://stackoverflow.com/q/5971686/4200639 pode ser útil para você, além do mais isso irá travar a sua tela até que o processo termine.

Comment: Estou lendo dados que proveem da Interface Gráfica, por isso o depurador está pedindo que seja STA.

Comment: O link indicado não ensina com configurar Apartment State para a classe Task.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, quando você utiliza o STA, você está segurando a tela para poder acessar os seus objetos, e quando você pensa em paralelismo que não bloqueia a tela você não pode utilizar o STA, mas sim invocar os objetos da tela para serem acessado. A sua dúvida é como utilizar a thread e não bloquear a tela principal, uma das forma é esta que eu te passei.

Comment: Pra você invocar um objeto que está em outra thread que é o seu caso, você pode utlizar este  exemplo: `textbox1.Invoke(new Action(()=>textbox1.Text="Olá"))`

Comment: Ok. Consegui fazer rodar. Mas, a tela continua congelada.

Comment: Eu precisava saber o que tem dentro do método `GeraRelatorio_Thread` pra te dar uma resposta mais apropriada, pois sempre que você acessa um objeto em tela o sistema vai travar nem que seja milissegundos. agora se você acessar todos os componentes da tela e ficar sempre manipulando-os a tela vai ficar congelada. A sua dúvida nesta pergunta é Como não bloquear a tela durante um processamento prolongado, neste caso a minha resposta faz isso, não bloqueia a tela.

Comment: Trata-se somente de um cruzamento de dados de tabelas. O programa já está rondando, mas parece que não está sendo criada outro thread.

Comment: Mas você faz algum acesso a tela durante o cruzamento de informação?

Answer (score 0):

Além da Task, você pode usar backgroundWorker.

Quando tu for acessar algo da interface, pra get ou set, vai ter que usar um dispatcher para acessar através da thread de ui, caso sua thread em execução seja de primeiro nível, quero dizer, se a thread principal foi quem a iniciou:

```
private void GeraRelatorio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();    
    bw.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        GeraRelatorio_Thread();
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        //acabou a execução, mas tu pode obter retorno de métodos e etc, fechar um loader...
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

}


private void GeraRelatorio_Thread(){
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        //aplica as alterações na ui
            grid.Clear() //por exemplo
                    }));

    ... //outras coisas que seu método executa
}
```