# Multi threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Gostaria de criar um programa para atuar várias threads em um processo, deixando-o mais rápido, ou seja, as threads trabalhando juntas para terminar o serviço mais rápido. Porém cada uma trabalha individualmente no processo.

Código exemplo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Soma s = new Soma();
        Thread[] Threads = new Thread[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.PrintNumbers));
        }

        foreach (Thread t in Threads)
            t.Start();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Soma
{
    double soma = 0;
    public void PrintNumbers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 != 0)
            {
                soma -= i;
            }
            else
            {
                soma += i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(soma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código é muito esquisito, provavelmente tem erros, mas não posso afirmar porque não sei o objetivo. O ideal é usar `Task` e não `Thread` e neste caso executará mais lento que se fizer sequencial. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101

Comment: Então, o objetivo é realmente responder se uma aplicação de múltiplas threads terá um resultado melhor, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que várias threads trabalhem no mesmo processo.(fins didáticos)

Comment: Não da pra dizer somente com um caso isolado como esse, pra esse seu código, só o fato da nova thread alocar novos recursos já ia deixar mais lento.

Comment: o código em si não é esse, é apenas um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pools de Threads. Exemplo:

```
using System;  
using System.Threading;  

public class Fibonacci  
{  
    private int _n;  
    private int _fibOfN;  
    private ManualResetEvent _doneEvent;  

    public int N { get { return _n; } }  
    public int FibOfN { get { return _fibOfN; } }  

    // Constructor.  
    public Fibonacci(int n, ManualResetEvent doneEvent)  
    {  
        _n = n;  
        _doneEvent = doneEvent;  
    }  

    // Wrapper method for use with thread pool.  
    public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)  
    {  
        int threadIndex = (int)threadContext;  
        Console.WriteLine("thread {0} started...", threadIndex);  
        _fibOfN = Calculate(_n);  
        Console.WriteLine("thread {0} result calculated...", threadIndex);  
        _doneEvent.Set();  
    }  

    // Recursive method that calculates the Nth Fibonacci number.  
    public int Calculate(int n)  
    {  
        if (n <= 1)  
        {  
            return n;  
        }  

        return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2);  
    }  
}  

public class ThreadPoolExample  
{  
    static void Main()  
    {  
        const int FibonacciCalculations = 10;  

        // One event is used for each Fibonacci object.  
        ManualResetEvent[] doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[FibonacciCalculations];  
        Fibonacci[] fibArray = new Fibonacci[FibonacciCalculations];  
        Random r = new Random();  

        // Configure and start threads using ThreadPool.  
        Console.WriteLine("launching {0} tasks...", FibonacciCalculations);  
        for (int i = 0; i < FibonacciCalculations; i++)  
        {  
            doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);  
            Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci(r.Next(20, 40), doneEvents[i]);  
            fibArray[i] = f;  
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f.ThreadPoolCallback, i);  
        }  

        // Wait for all threads in pool to calculate.  
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);  
        Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete.");  

        // Display the results.  
        for (int i= 0; i<FibonacciCalculations; i++)  
        {  
            Fibonacci f = fibArray[i];  
            Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci({0}) = {1}", f.N, f.FibOfN);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Fonte: [Como usar um pool de threads (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/how-to-use-a-thread-pool)

Answer (score 0):

Se as suas operações não realizam operações de `IO`, ou se não pode utilizar o `.net 4.5` ou posterior, pode fazer uso do `Parallel.For`.

```
var s = new Soma();
Parallel.For(0, 5, i => PrintNumbers());
```

agora se está à utilizar o `.net 4.5` ou posterior, poderá fazer uso das palavras magicas `async/await`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(Exec).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task Exec()
{
    var s = new Soma();
    var tasks = new Task[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        tasks[i] = s.PrintNumbers();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

class Soma
{
    double soma = 0;
    public async Task PrintNumbers()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 != 0)
            {
                soma -= i;
            }
            else
            {
                soma += i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(soma);
    }
}
```

Porem o `Parallel.For` tem uma vantagem sobre o `async/await`, o mesmo cria um particionamento interno para evitar que seja criadas mais Threads que o necessário.

Porém também particionar as suas `Tasks` de forma manual, porém não terá à ajuda do `Parallel` para calcular o numero ideal de partições.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(Exec).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task Exec()
{
    var s = new Soma();
    var particoes = 3;
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, particoes).Select(x => Task.CompletedTask).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        var particao = i % particoes;
        tasks[particao] = tasks[particao].ContinueWith(async t => await s.PrintNumbers());
    }           
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

class Soma
{
    double soma = 0;
    public async Task PrintNumbers()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 != 0)
            {
                soma -= i;
            }
            else
            {
                soma += i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(soma);
    }
}
```