# Qual a diferença entre Task e async Task?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo, task

No código abaixo escrevi dois métodos, um com o retorno `Task` e outro `async Task`. O que acontece de diferente na execução desses métodos já que para um adicionei na construção a palavra reservada `await`e no outro não.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{            
    var result = await KmToMiles(1d);
    Console.WriteLine("Km to miles: {0}", result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static async Task<double> KmToMiles(double value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(KmToMiles));
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return value * 0.621371;
}

public static Task<double> KmToMiles(double value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(KmToMiles));
    Task.Delay(1000);
    return Task.FromResult<double>(value * 0.621371);
}
```

Comment: Acho que a diferença, basicamente, é que um é síncrono (`Task`) e o outro assíncrono (`async Task`).

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123173/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-task-e-thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando usa um `async` está permitindo que o método seja executado assincronamente com outro método. Métodos assíncronos sempre retornam nada ou retornam um tarefa que dará resultado no futuro, por isso usamos algum tipo `Task`, é ela que sabe gerenciar isso.

De forma geral retornar um `Task` sem um `async` não ajuda muito porque encapsulamos o retorno em uma tarefa que não pode ser assíncrona. O único motivo para fazer isto é ter um método intermediário que precise receber uma informação assíncrona de outro método e passar adiante. Note que nesse ponto não há assincronicidade, o que em si não é um problema se usado corretamente. Esse método será bloqueante, mas se ele está em um local que isso não importa pode ser útil. Sem poder fazer isto teria que fazer códigos "linguições" que provavelmente teriam mais de uma responsabilidade. Mas lembre-se que ele é bloqueante.

No seu exemplo o segundo método só não executará assincronamente retornando o resultado encapsulado. Geralmente isso é errado porque `async` é bom com IO e não com processamento. Em exemplo assim o final será o mesmo só que o primeiro deixa outras coisas executarem durante o *delay* e o segundo não permitirá isto, a diferença é o `async`, que no primeiro obriga o uso do `Task`, e no segundo, usando desta forma não faz muito sentido exceto para compatibilizar as chamadas já que usando um `await` espera um tarefa e não o valor bruto.

Só lembrando que esse código só faz sentido se cada método estiver em um *namespace* diferente e só um deles for importado no momento da chamada, o que na prática torna pouco vantajoso ter essa compatibilidade porque para trocar a implementação tem que mexer no código de qualquer forma, e exigir rever todo ele pode até ser benéfico.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).