# Quantas threads o .NET suporta no máximo?

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Existe um limite de *threads* que podem rodar ao mesmo tempo no .NET? Depende do sistema operacional? É possível mudar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De alguma forma sempre depende do sistema operacional, e mais ainda do hardware que está rodando. Justamente porque não tem um limite estabelecido pelo .NET. E pode não ter pelo sistema operacional também, a não ser o limite da capacidade, especialmente de memória, para criar novas. Obviamente que há um mapeamento do .NET para as *threads* do SO.

Lembre-se que cada *thread* é um objeto que ocupa espaço na memória. E se ela estiver ativa ainda precisa de uma pilha de execução, que pode ser bem grande (pode configurar o tamanho individualmente), então a quantidade não deveria ser exagerada. Até mesmo pelo processamento. Se tiver muitas, o tempo gasto em troca entre elas pode ser muito superior ao ganho, ainda mais que o ganho maior sempre vem da quantidade de *threads* igual à quantidade de processadores. Depois disso o ganho vem de IO, e existem técnicas melhores para lidar com isso, usando [`Task`s](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101).

Existe um valor padrão que o .NET usa para a [*thread pool*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Foi aumentando ao longo do tempo, ainda mais em 64 bits onde pode rodar realmente muitas. Em geral isso varia conforme a quantidade de processadores existentes, mas pode mudar.

Não precisa se preocupar com isso. Mas pode [impor um limite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=net-8.0#system-threading-threadpool-setmaxthreads(system-int32-system-int32)) artificial para a aplicação não sair do controle em certas situações que você permite criar *threads* arbitrariamente. Obviamente que há um limite de ~2 bilhões aí, então é claro que tem algum limite, mas ele é muito maior do que pode manipular.