# Como fazer interação a partir de Aplicaçao WEB para máquinas clientes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma aplicação WEB em `ASP.NET MVC` que é um projeto de intranet. Gostaria de adicionar algumas funcionalidades nela pra facilitar mais os trabalhos com Backup's.

Já tenho um `WIDNOWSFORMS APPLICATION` que executa  os backups com interação com o usuário e os salva em um servidor na rede.  E também a mesma aplicação só que em forma de `WINDOWS SERVICE` que faz os backups automaticamente em um determinado horário e também os salva em um servidor na rede.

Cada uma das aplicações serve em um cenário, porém o que estou querendo é: Integrar a Aplicação `ASP.NET MVC` pra quando, por exemplo, eu quiser fazer backup drivers de uma determinada máquina de um usuário, eu selecione esta opção na Aplicação WEB, ela envia a mensagem(De alguma forma para a máquina, penso que pode se comunicar com o serviço) e a máquina faz o Backup e salva no servidor.

Como eu posso fazer isso, através de WEB API, algum outro modo ?

Comment: Está tudo muito abstrato, acho que é isso, mas é chute. Pode ser que tenha algo que impeça dependo do que for fazer, mas não tem como responder, a gente não sabe o que será feito. Na forma atual está bem difícil responder.

Comment: @bigown o que estou buscando eh a forma de interação app web com um serviço. Um exemplo eh um antivírus. A pessoa na console Web da o comando para escanear e o Antivírus faz a verificação. O que to querendo saber é como essa comunicação acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que entendi você quer "automatizar" alguns processos que já existem e que hoje necessitam de uma interação humana para serem realizados ou simplesmente VOCÊ, e não o usuário, indique quando fazer.

Como isso deve partir da aplicação web e recebida pela aplicação desktop, acredito que criar um serviço do windows "Windows Service", em c#, no cliente resolva seu problema.

Na aplicação web você informa o que deve ser feito (guarda isso em uma tabela do banco de dados) e a aplicação "Windows Service", no cliente, de tempo em tempo verifica e processa essa(s) informação(ões).

- Por segurança, crie um "Web Service" para leitura dessa "tabela" (não deixe informações de conexão de banco de dados no cliente).
- Use um token para validar o acesso ao Web Service
- Coloque um intervalo de tempo que atenda suas necessidades, que não ocasione conexões desnecessárias no banco de dados e sobrecarga de processamento na máquina do cliente.
- Traga de uma só vez uma lista das "ações" a serem executadas no cliente, evitando assim vários acessos ao banco de dados.

**Dica para rodar a aplicação em um intervalo de tempo:**

```
do
{
    ProcessaAcoes();
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 2); //de 2 em 2 horas
} while (true);
```

Comment: Dica: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101

Comment: Muito bom @bigown não conhecia, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o assunto. Marquei como comentário útil, obrigado! :)