# Diferença entre Thread.Sleep e Task.Delay

Tags: c#, thread, task

Estou desenvolvendo uma comunicação cliente / servidor, e utilizando `Task` para comunicação assíncrona.

Anteriormente, já havia feito outra comunicação onde utilizei `Thread`, funciona sem problemas e consome pouco processamento.

Nessa agora com `Task` tive um processamento elevado, e parecia não acontecer o Delay entre iterações do `while`. Resolvi trocar todos os `Task.Delay` por `Thread.Sleep`.

E o resultado foi satisfatório. Passou a ter o delay a cada iteração e o consumo do CPU se manteve baixo.

Eis a questão: 
Qual a diferença entre `Task.Delay()` e `Thread.Sleep()`

> Trecho de código onde um `TcpListener` aceita as conexões 
>   (Esse trecho fica dentro da execução de uma `Task`):

```
while  (_running)
{
    if (server.Pending())
    {
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        string nIP = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
        ChatServerClient clie = new ChatServerClient(++_idControl, client, this._log);
        _clients.Add(clie);
        ClientConnected(new ClientChatEventArgs() { Client = clie });
        clie.OnClientStop += clie_OnClientStop;
        clie.StartClient();
        clie.Enviar.Enqueue("Servidor Conectado.");
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //Funciona, baixo CPU e espera o tempo
        //Task.Delay(2000); //Não funciona, alto CPU e não espera o tempo
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86014/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Levando em consideração o seguinte exemplo

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private async void button2_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

**`public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)`**

Esta é a forma clássica de suspender a execução. Este método irá suspender o segmento atual até que a quantidade de tempo tenha decorrido. Quando você chama *Thread.Sleep* da maneira acima, não há nada que você possa fazer para abortar isso, exceto esperar até o tempo decorrer ou reiniciar o aplicativo. Isso porque *Thread.Sleep* suspende o segmento que está fazendo a chamada. E por eu estar chamando *Thread.Sleep* no meu manipulador de eventos de botão, a interface do usuário fica congelada até que o tempo especificado termine.

**`public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)`**

*Task.Delay* age de uma maneira muito diferente do *Thread.Sleep*. Basicamente, *Task.Delay* criará uma tarefa que será completada após uma demora. *Task.Delay* não está bloqueia a interface do usuário e a mesma continuará respondendo.

Por trás das cenas há um cronômetro até o horário especificado. Uma vez que o temporizador controla o atraso, podemos cancelar o atraso a qualquer momento simplesmente parando o temporizador. Para cancelar a execução do *Task.Delay* você tem que passar mais o parâmetro *CancellationToken cancellationToken*. Podendo ficar da seguinte forma o exemplo.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private async void button2_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000, tokenSource.Token);
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Um detalhe importante a resaltar, é a implementação de async no Task.Delay.
Que conforme documentação o Asynchrony é essencial para as atividades que estão potencialmente sendo bloqueadas, assim como quando sua aplicação acessa a Web. O acesso a um recurso da Web às vezes é lento ou atrasado. Se tal atividade for bloqueada dentro de um processo síncrono, todo o aplicativo deverá esperar. Em um processo assíncrono, o aplicativo poderá prosseguir com outro trabalho que não dependa do recurso da Web até a tarefa potencialmente causadora do bloqueio terminar.

---

Referência:

<sub>[Visual C#: Thread.Sleep vs. Task.Delay](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx). Disponível em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0. Acesso em: 08 Dez. 2017.</sub>

<sub>[Programação assíncrona com Async e Await (C# e Visual Basic)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx). Disponível em: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx. Acesso em: 08 Dez. 2017.</sub>